# Link prediction in a network using GNNs versus Matrix Completion and other methods

Tags: graphs, neural-networks, factoring

I am looking at some social network analysis and I need to do link prediction. By link prediction I mean that I only have a subset of the relationships in the network, and I need to make predictions about the unseen relationships.

I am familiar with the more traditional or common methods for link prediction from
simple things like logistic regression, to fancier methods like matrix completion and matrix factorization method. Of course, there are a new class of algorithms like Graphical Neural Networks, which I know about but have not worked with in an detail.

As I start working on this social network analysis project, I was hoping someone could tell me whether GNNs work better or worse than the more traditional or earlier methods? I don't want to reach for the shiny new neural network approach without trying to find some papers or benchmarking efforts. I was wondering if anyone knew of any papers that compute these benchmarks, or whether someone just has some anecdotal experience with link prediction methods.

Comment: What research have you done?  The way to tell is to read some papers that use GNNs, and see if they compare to prior methods.  I would bet that they do.  The way to find such papers is to do a literature search.  We expect you to do that before asking here, and show us what you've found so far.

Comment: @D.W. I don't think this comment is particularly helpful. Have I done a search of the literature--of couse I have. That is what I said above when referencing various methods like matrix completion and matrix factorization as well as GNN. But there is a difference between the toy examples in a paper, versus the practical experience of trying link prediction on real datasets. So I was hoping that someone with link prediction experience might suggest how well GNNs perform versus other methods.

Comment: Great!  Perhaps you can summarize in the question what papers you've found that compare GNNs with prior methods, and what the findings of those papers are, and contrast that with what you want to know.  This will provide context to others who are considering answering about what you already know, and provide background for others who come across this question that is more likely to make the question interesting and useful to them.